is there a ordered dictionary/ map in golang
is there a ordered dictionary/ map in golang?. what options do i have? in python i have ordered dicts. what options do i have?
// this is not ordered
src map[string]interface{}

// this is not ordered
src map[string]string{}

i got this

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/wk8/go-ordered-map,
https://github.com/elliotchance/orderedmap/.

just want to check if this is inbuilt available?

AFAIK there is no such collection in the Go standard library. You have to build your own or import a library.

There is no build in sorted map, but an open proposal.
The best you can do in Go 1.23 is
import (
    "maps"
    "slices"
)

...

    for _, k := range slices.Sorted(maps.Keys(m)) {
        ...
    }

Otherwise, there are examples and a discussion of libraries in the open issue.
